# Im using ember with ember-modal-dialog package. Is there a way to pass a model into the close action cancelAlarmEdit?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
{{#each alarms as |alarm|}}
  {{if alarm.isEditing}}
    {{#modal-dialog translucentOverlay=true close="cancelAlarmEdit"}}
      //this works down here
      <button type="btn btn-danger" {{action 'cancelAlarmEdit' alarm}}</button>
    {{/modal-dialog}}
  {{else}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}
```

Is there a way to pass a model into cancelAlarmEdit from the close tag above? I had trouble finding relevant info on it from https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this should work:

```
{{#modal-dialog close=(action 'cancelAlarmEdit' alarm)}}
```

Actually the `{{action}}` helper is pretty similar to Javascripts `bind`.

Comment: Thanks, the method you described worked for me. I had defined the controller for this template in route, but i chose to split up the route.js and controller.js which may have also helped to fix the problem for me. I defined the cancelAlarmEdit function there instead and it fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see such feature neither in docs, nor in the source code of this addon. You may try to create a new component, based on this addon's:

```
// app/components/modal-dialog.js
import ModalDialog from 'ember-modal-dialog/components/modal-dialog';

export default ModalDialog.extend({
  actions: {
    close() {
      this.sendAction('close', this.get('closeParam'));
    }
  }
});
```

In template your should be able to pass `closeParam` attribute.

And if you will not succeed in extending, it's not that hard to write your own modal component.